# why is the difference in address of character and int in a structure in c =4 and not 1

Tags: c, struct, char, size

I gave the following input in the below code
a 12.5 12
b 13.5 13
c 14.5 14

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

struct book
{
char name;
float price;
int pages;
};

struct book b1,b2,b3;



printf("enter name , price ,& no of pages\n");
scanf(" %c %f %d",&b1.name,&b1.price,&b1.pages);



scanf(" %c %f %d",&b2.name,&b2.price,&b2.pages);


scanf(" %c %f %d",&b3.name,&b3.price,&b3.pages);



printf("%c %d %f %d %d %d",b1.name,&b1.name,b1.price,&b1.price,b1.pages,&b1.pages);

printf("\n%c %d %f %d %d %d",b2.name,&b2.name,b2.price,&b2.price,b2.pages,&b2.pages);

printf("\n%c %d %f %d %d %d",b3.name,&b3.name,b3.price,&b3.price,b3.pages,&b3.pages);

printf("\n%d %d %d",sizeof(b1.name),sizeof(b1.price), sizeof(b1.pages));

}
```

And I got the following output

a 2686740 12.500000 2686744 12 2686748
b 2686728 13.500000 2686732 13 2686736
c 2686716 14.500000 2686720 14 2686724
1 4 4

Now what I can't understand is that the difference between the address of b1.name(2686740) and b1.price(2686744) is 4 wheres b1.name is a character so the difference should have been 1 and the same is repeated in b2 and b3 also.  Please help!!!

Comment: What you have stumbled upon is called "byte padding". Research about it and you will get good articles to help you understand it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-packing

Comment: well I didn't even knew what padding is so I cant search according to it

Comment: It’s the compiler that you use add the padding in struct.

Comment: The correct format specifier for pointers is %p, not %d.

Answer (score 3):

It is because of structure **padding**.

Architecture of a computer processor is such a way that it can read 1 word from memory at a time.

To make use of this advantage of processor, data are always aligned as 4 bytes package which leads to insert empty addresses between other member’s address. e.g on 64 bit system,**int** should start at address divisible by 4, and **long** by 8, **short** by 2.

Padding is on by default. It inserts the following **gaps** into your first structure:

```
struct book
{
   char name;
   char padded_gap[3]; //padding extra 3 bytes
   float price;
   int pages;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a struct with different types could be packed tightly (which means the difference between addresses will be as you thought):

```
|--0--|--1--|--2--|--3--||||--4--|--5--|--6--|--7--||||--8--|--9--|--10--|--11--|
   c     f0    f1    f2       f3    i0    i1    i2    i3
```

This can be achieved by using `#pragma pack(1)`

*#pragma pack instructs the compiler to pack structure members with particular alignment*

But, since you didn't order the compiler to pack in 1-byte chunks, it is packing in n-byte chunks, where `n = size of largest type inside struct`, which in your case is 4-byte, resulting in:

```
|--0--|--1--|--2--|--3--||||--4--|--5--|--6--|--7--||||--8--|--9--|--10--|--11--|
   c    pad0  pad1  pad2      f0    f1    f2       f3    i0    i1    i2     i3
```

---

Play a bit with this snippet:

```
struct A{
    char c;   // has 7 bytes padding due to having a double in the struct
    double d; // size 8
}AA;

    printf("%d\n", sizeof(AA));

// feel free to change the parameter inside the pragma pack
#pragma pack(1) 
struct B{
    char c;   // has no padding due to pack(1)
    double d;
}BB;
#pragma pack(0)

    printf("%d\n", sizeof(BB));

#pragma pack(2)
struct C{
    char c;    // has only 1 byte padding
    double d;
}CC;
#pragma pack(0)

    printf("%d\n", sizeof(CC));
```